# Cocoa WebView: Cannot call Specific Javascript method using `callWebScriptMethod:`

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview

I am loading a page into a WebView. The page has this little-test Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(parametr)
{

  $('#testspan').html(parametr);

}

var bdu = (function(){
 return {
  secondtest: function(parametr) {

  $('#testspan').html(parametr);

  }
 }
})();
</script>
```

The problem is that I can't call the "secondtest" function from cocoa

this is perfectly work:

```
[[webview1 windowScriptObject] callWebScriptMethod:@"test" withArguments:arguments];
```

and this is not working:

```
[[webview1 windowScriptObject] callWebScriptMethod:@"bdu.secondtest" withArguments:arguments];
```

What would cause this problem and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I'll post this as comment instead of an answer: I don't know much about Javascript but it looks like the secondTest function is imbedded inside a block which itself is inside a function call. I don't see how anything external to script can resolve it as a callable function. (If this does work in Javascript, that language is an even bigger train wreck than I thought.) I would remove the function from its embedding and see if it works. If it does, then the embedding is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this for some time in Cordova MacOSX and here is the solution I found and works for me:

JavaScript:

```
CordovaBridgeUtil.isObject = function(obj) { return obj.constructor == Object; };
```

ObjectiveC:

```
WebScriptObject* bridgeUtil = [win evaluateWebScript:@"CordovaBridgeUtil"];
NSNumber* result = [bridgeUtil callWebScriptMethod:@"isObject" withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item]];
```

Answer (score 1):

"callWebScriptMethod" is meant to call a given method on a given webscript (i.e. javascript) object. On your second line you want to call the "secondTest" method on the javascript object named "bdu". The way to do this is to:

1. Get the bdu object from your window object:

   `WebScriptObject* bdu =[[webview1 windowScriptObject] valueForKey:@"bdu"];`
2. Call the "secondTest" method on the bdu object:

   `[bdu callWebScriptMethod:@"secondtest" withArguments:arguments];`

Answer (score 0):

> callWebscriptMethod:(NSString*)name withArguments:(NSArray*)args:

does not evaluate `name` as a Javascript expression. So it can't parse `bdu.secondtest`: it doesn't look up `bdu` first, then get the entry `secondtest` in it.

Instead, just use `evaluateWebScript:`.